# how to Install java run-time /jre on a custom path using a Batch script?

Tags: windows-7, installation, batch-file, automated-install, windows-installer

Im trying to create a bat file to make an unattended installation with sccm. 
I downloaded jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe from  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html  (jre-7u55-windows-i586 is used for legacy application we are running)

and followed https://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml
and could come in to

"%~dp0**jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe**" /s /v"AgreeToLicense=YES INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55 IEXPLORER=1 MOZILLA=1 REBOOT=SUPRESS JAVAUPDATE=0 SYSTRAY=0"

Above script will work only if the installation directory is other than C:\Program Files\

For example it will work if

```
INSTALLDIR=**C:\test\**test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55
```

..

But I want INSTALLDIR to be

```
C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55
```

I tried adding following

`INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55"` --- not working

`INSTALLDIR='C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55'` --- not working

`/INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55`  --- not working

`"INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55"` --- not working

All the time im getting this .. (Sounds rather misleading message)

[image]

I cant understand why i cant install it on C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55.. What Im missing here? What is wrong with C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55 . Pls help

(I do have admin rights for my account)

Comment: Not a fix, but a workaround might be to use the old 8.3 short name, eg. C:\Program Files is usually C:\Progra~1.  These short names can be seen with dir /x from a command prompt. It also might help narrow down that it's a path issue, not a permissions issue.

Comment: try using the %programfiles% environment variable, maybe this is a case of 32 vs 64 bits trouble. The 32 bits will not see the same program files path as the 64 bits one.

Comment: already tried this one %programfiles% .. no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the short names from the full path to overcome the limits mentioned in your question.

```
REM Insert full path to executable here as a literal string or environment
Call :s_Install_Short "C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55"
Goto :EOF

:s_Install_Short
REM Block attempts to pass no parameter
If "%~1" EQU "" Goto :EOF

REM %~s1 contains the path in the first parameter as a shortened string
"%~dp0jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe" /s /v"AgreeToLicense=YES INSTALLDIR=%~s1 IEXPLORER=1 MOZILLA=1 REBOOT=SUPRESS JAVAUPDATE=0 SYSTRAY=0"

Goto :EOF
```

The use of `%~s1` would turn `C:\Program Files\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55` into something similar to `C:\PROGRA~1\test\test1\Java\jre1.7.0.55`